# Error in "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore" and "-Djakarta.net.ssl.trustStore"

Tags: java, quarkus, truststore, jakarta-migration

I am trying to configure a project with Quarkus 3.0.2.Final, java11 but I am experiencing problems with system variables.
in other projects I can configure the "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore" and I can properly configure the trustStore (with the right password) but then when I try to configure a project with the same dependencies I have to use the "-Djakarta.net.ssl.trustStore"(otherwise gives me error).  I have to use the -Djavax because I have a Docker base image that configures this parameter.
[these are my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBtS9.png)

any idea why I am encountering this error ?
Thank you.

I expect to configure with "-Djavax" and not with "-Djakarta"

Comment: Because when i execute the jar with this configurations in the command line -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore(also with the pass config) i can send the request because the certificate is configured correctly, but in my other project(with the same dependencies) when i try to execute the jar with those configs "-Djavax" i get an error :   PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. and if i change with the "-Djakarta" suffix this error be canceled.

Comment: I don’t understand why I have to use jakarta instead of javax, which in the other project I use javax without problems